# Error Message when popup window is loaded

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, force.com

I have created 2 popup on 2 button. And have a object (AC). On both popup I have some fields to insert.

In 1st popup it contain A.name1, A.name2, A.date, A.Edate, A.Pjt etc and in 2nd popup I have fields A.Name1, A.name2. The A.Name1 and A.name2 are required field in object.

My problem is that when I try to insert the value in the 1st popup I am getting error meg that "YOU MUST ENTER A VALUE" but even then i enter the value. So I commented the 2nd popup then it is working fine but when 2nd popup is uncommented the this error is thrown event the value is entered. The 2nd popup contains the same 2 fields in the first with some other fields.

can anybody help me to find the solution for this error.

```xml
<apex:outputPanel id="tstpopup">
    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}"/>
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="custPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}">
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageblocksection >
                <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                <apex:outputlabel value="name1: " />
                <apex:inputfield id="proj" value="{!AC.name1__c}" />
                </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                <apex:outputlabel value="name2: " />
                <apex:inputfield id="role" value="{!AC.name2__c}" />
                </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                <p/>
                <apex:commandbutton value="Pencil in a New Project" action="{!save}"   />
                <apex:commandbutton value="Cancel" action="{!closePopup}" immediate="true" /><br/><br/><br/>
                </apex:pageblocksection>
                </apex:pageblock>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>


 <apex:outputPanel id="tstpopup1">
    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}"/>
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="custPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}">
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageblocksection >
                <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                <apex:outputlabel value="name1: " />
                <apex:inputfield id="proj1" value="{!AC.name1__c}" />
                </apex:pageblocksectionitem><p/>
                <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                <apex:outputlabel value="Date: " />
                <apex:inputfield id="sd" value="{!AC.Date__c}" />
                </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                <apex:outputlabel value="EDate: " />
                <apex:inputfield id="ed" value="{!AC.EDate__c}" />
                </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                <apex:outputlabel value="Proj: " />
                <apex:inputfield id="pl" value="{!AC.Pjt__c}" />
                </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                <apex:outputlabel value="Charge: " />
                <apex:inputfield id="charge" value="{!AC.Charge__c}" />
                </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                <apex:outputlabel value="Name2: " />
                <apex:inputfield id="role1" value="{!AC.name2__c}" />
                </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                <apex:outputlabel value="time: " />
                <apex:inputfield id="overtime" value="{!AC.time__c}" />
                </apex:pageblocksectionitem>                   
                </apex:pageblocksection>
                <apex:commandbutton value="Assign to a New Project" action="{!assign}"   />
                <apex:commandbutton value="Cancel" action="{!closePopup}" immediate="true" /><br/><br/><br/>
                </apex:pageblock>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Could you provide the second popup?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you have the same object in two popups. If you enters a value eg. name1_*c in your first popup - the other field name1*_c in your second popup is still empty.

Try to create two diferent instances of your object:

Apex class:

```
public YourObject AC1 { get; set; }
public YourObject AC2 { get; set; }

// Constructor
public YourClassName(){
    AC1 = new YourObject();
    AC2 = new YourObject();
}
```

First popup:

```salesforce
<apex:outputPanel styleClass="custPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp1}">
    <apex:pageblock >
        <apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:commandbutton value="Assign to a New Project" action="{!assign1}"   />
            <apex:commandbutton value="Cancel" action="{!closePopup1}" immediate="true" />            
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageblocksection >
            <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                <apex:outputlabel value="name1: " />
                <apex:inputfield id="proj1" value="{!AC1.name1__c}" />
            </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
            <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                <apex:outputlabel value="Name2: " />
                <apex:inputfield id="role1" value="{!AC1.name2__c}" />
            </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
            <!-- other fields from the instance 1 of the object -->
            ....
        </apex:pageblocksection>
    <apex:pageblock >
<apex:outputPanel>
```

Second popup:

```salesforce
<apex:outputPanel styleClass="custPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp2}">
    <apex:pageblock >
        <apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:commandbutton value="Assign to a Another Project" action="{!assign2}"   />
            <apex:commandbutton value="Cancel" action="{!closePopup2}" immediate="true" />            
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageblocksection >
            <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                <apex:outputlabel value="name1: " />
                <apex:inputfield id="proj2" value="{!AC2.name1__c}" />
            </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
            <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                <apex:outputlabel value="Name2: " />
                <apex:inputfield id="role2" value="{!AC2.name2__c}" />
            </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
            <!-- other fields from the instance 2 of the object -->
            ....
        </apex:pageblocksection>
    <apex:pageblock >
    <apex:outputPanel>
```